# Cholesky inverse

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

I have the Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$ of a symmetric positive definite matrix. I then compute a result in the form of $A=LXL^T$, where $A$ and $X$ are also symmetric positive definite matrices.

I know $A$ and I would like to retrieve $X$. The easy way would be to invert $L$ so we have $X=L^{-1}AL^{-T}$, however this requires to invert a matrix. I know that the inverse of a triangular matrix is not too difficult to compute but is there a better way to compute $X$?

**Edit**

To provide more background, I already know $A$ in a diagonalized way, for example I have $A=PDP^T$, with $D$ a diagonal definite positive matrix and $PP^T=P^TP=I$. Still, I need to get to $X$ somehow, ideally with no matrix inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve $PDP^T = LXL^T$ with matrices as specified, compute the diagonal matrix $R$ such that $RR^T = D$ by taking the square roots of the diagonal entries.
then you have:

$PRR^TP^T = LCC^TL^T$ where $CC^T = X$

We can then determine $C$ by solving $PR = LC$ which can be performed directly by any number of triangular solvers.

### Edit

Since maintaining the Cholesky decomposition of all matrices in such computations is often numerically preferable, it is highly recommended to work with these as much as possible. Rank-1 updates such as `cholupdate` may also be helpful in this effort.

Comment: I am not familiar with `cholupdate`, is there an implementation in Python/numpy/scipy/tf?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/cholesky_update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636518/dense-cholesky-update-in-python